# How to write foldr (right fold) generator in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, fold

Python's `reduce` is a left-fold, which means it is tail-recursive and its uses can be neatly rewritten as a loop. However, Python does not have a built-in function for doing right folds. Since right-folds are most naturally written with recursion (and Python doesn't like recursion as much as functional languages), I'm interested in writing a right fold (`foldr`) in terms of a generator.

How can this be done? And very specifically, how can it be done in Python 2.7?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that one of the benefits to `foldr` is that you can sometimes fold on infinite lists without risk of eating your stack alive. I would like to see answers that preserve this property.

For example, Haskell's `foldr` is lazy on both input and output and can allow for short-circuiting "step" functions to work on long/infinite inputs:

```
foldr (&&) True (repeat False)  -- gives False
```

Any Python variant that uses `list`/`reversed`/etc. on the input will hang if given `itertools.repeat(some_value)`.

Note that Python's `reduce` chokes in the same example because of strictness:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, itertools.repeat(False), True) # hangs
```

Comment: I think in order to do this, your generator would have to `yield` a generator that `yield`s a generator that .... that if the passed argument is an empty list, `yield`s the initial value... Which sounds a bit headache-inducing, frankly... Python is fine with recursion, as long as it's of reasonable depth, but I'm not entirely sure that recursion and generators play all that well together...

Comment: The definition of haskell foldr is just reduce, foldl will fail on an infinite list.

Comment: Python's `reduce` is a left-fold, so it's like Haskell's `foldl'` (note the prime). Yes, `foldl` and its variants will fail on an infinite list, which is why one might desire to use a right fold.

Comment: Understood, unfortunately function calls are not lazy in python so if you were to implement `foldr` as `f(x, f(x, f(x, ....)))` then all of the functions will get evaluated immediately and therefore fail on infinite list even if the function is defined as say `def lor(a,b): a or b`, while the `or` is lazy the `b`  parameter isn't.

Comment: @achampion Thanks. I realized that in the course of working through this question/answer. I'll give a little more time for thought before selecting an answer.

Comment: Do you actually want a right fold or would a short-circuiting left fold be fine?

Answer (score 2):

So a simple generator in python (without appropriate error checking):

```
def foldr(op, lst):
    l, x = reversed(list(lst)), None
    for i in l:
        if not x:
            x = i
            continue
        x = op(x, i)
        yield x
```

e.g.:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> for i in foldr(mul, [1,2,3,4]):
...     print i
24
24
12
```

Almost identical to the 'roughly equivalent' implementation of reduce in the documentation:

```
def foldr(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = reversed(list(iterable))
    if initializer is None:
        try:
            initializer = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('foldr() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = initializer
    for x in it:
        accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
        yield accum_value
```

[Edit]
So purely as an exercise of the mind and with very little practical value, it is possible to defer as long as there is some cooperation between the function that you a folding over... e.g.:

```
class Defer(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.func(*self.args)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.func(*self.args)

def foldr(function, iterable, initializer):
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        return function(next(it), Defer(foldr, function, it, initializer))
    except StopIteration:
        return initializer
```

Then as long as the function converts to the right type you can defer the calculation, however this will not work with native operators, so not sure how useful this really is:

```
>>> print(foldr(lambda a, b: int(a)*int(b), [1,2,3,4], 1))
24
```

Defining a forever generator:

```
from itertools import repeat
def forever():
    yield False
    yield True
    for i in repeat(False):
        yield i
```

Folding `or` across an infinite list, returns when it finds a True

```
>>> print(foldr(lambda a, b: bool(a) or bool(b), forever(), False))
True
```

Comment: What if `lst` is a generator?

Comment: Then you need to operate on iterables... `l = list(lst)`. You will need to expand the full generator in order to do foldr.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to catch appropriate exceptions but should be an idea of how to do it iteratively:

```
def foldr(a, b, l):
    if isinstance(l, Iterator):
        it = reversed(list(l))
    else:
        it = reversed(l)
    try:
       nxt = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return 
    c = a(nxt, b)  
    stop = object() 
    while nxt is not stop:
        yield c
        nxt = next(it, stop)
        c = a(nxt, c) if nxt is not stop else c



from operator import truediv
for c in (foldr(truediv, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])):
    print(c)
```

Comment: What if `l` is itself a generator?

Comment: @3noch, you cannot reverse a generator/iterator so it would depend on what you consider an acceptable alternative

Comment: can you add an example how it works in  with an infinite list?

Comment: How can you do foldr on an infinite list?

Comment: @3noch, so what happens on infinite input, does the foldr intermittently return or short circuits after `n` elements are processed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It depends on the stepping function. If the stepping function does not take the next item in the input, then the fold can yield immediately without further recursion.

Comment: @3noch, the only way I can see that you could replicate is using some form of parallel processing. Once you `itertools.repeat(False)` then you are in an infinite loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think I'm realizing that the ability of Haskell's `foldr` to handle infinite lists is because of implicit laziness on the input. Python's strict semantics will always demand the "next" item from the infinite list unless you build a special interface.

Comment: @3noch, it is definitely the input that is the problem, once you call list on an infinite iterator then you are stuck in that process. I don't see any easy way even using threads or parallel processing to be able to replicate the haskell behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to define a function using generators, why not use the following?

```
def foldr(op, lst):
    return reduce(op, reversed(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
def foldr(fn, seq, init):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        x = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        try:
            for elem in init:
                yield elem
        except TypeError:
            yield init
    else:
        try:
            for elem in fn(x, foldr(fn, it, init)):
                yield elem
        except TypeError:
            yield fn(x, foldr(fn, it, init))
```

It's not exactly production-ready since it will hit the Python stack limit pretty quickly and it will be surprising in the presence of side-effecting functions due to the double call to `fn`, but it should be enough to give you an idea.