# Struggling to figure out how to trace code for folder function

Tags: python, lambda, higher-order-functions

I'm struggling to figure out how do higher order functions work, more specifically folder functions. I ran it through *pythontutor* a couple of times, however I don't quite understand how to trace the code correctly.

```
def fold(op, f, n):
    if n==0:
        return f(0)
    else:
        return op(f(n), fold(op, f, n-1))

fold(lambda x,y:x-y, x, 4)
```

Comment: I think the edit unintentionally changed foldr (right fold) to folder, which is likely not the intended question. Perhaps OP can clarify.

Comment: See these existing questions in case they are of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366374/what-is-the-pythonic-equivalent-to-the-fold-function-from-functional-program, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372983/how-to-write-foldr-right-fold-generator-in-python

Comment: yep the original function was specifically a foldr function.